# Flink Streaming: From one window, lookup state in another window

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have two streams:

- Measurements
- WhoMeasured (metadata about who took the measurement)

These are the case classes for them:

```
case class Measurement(var value: Int, var who_measured_id: Int)
case class WhoMeasured(var who_measured_id: Int, var name: String)
```

The `Measurement` stream has a lot of data. The `WhoMeasured` stream has little. In fact, for each `who_measured_id` in the `WhoMeasured` stream, only 1 name is relevant, so old elements can be discarded if one with the same `who_measured_id` arrives. This is essentially a HashTable that gets filled by the `WhoMeasured` stream.

In my custom window function

```
class WFunc extends WindowFunction[Measurement, Long, Int, TimeWindow] {
  override def apply(key: Int, window: TimeWindow, input: Iterable[Measurement], out: Collector[Long]): Unit = {

    // Here I need access to the WhoMeasured stream to get the name of the person who took a measurement
    // The following two are equivalent since I keyed by who_measured_id
    val name_who_measured = magic(key)
    val name_who_measured = magic(input.head.who_measured_id)
  }
}
```

This is my job. Now as you might see, there is something missing: The combination of the two streams.

```
val who_measured_stream = who_measured_source
  .keyBy(w => w.who_measured_id)
  .countWindow(1)

val measurement_stream = measurements_source
  .keyBy(m => m.who_measured_id)
  .timeWindow(Time.seconds(60), Time.seconds(5))
  .apply(new WFunc)
```

So in essence this is sort of a lookup table that gets updated when new elements in the `WhoMeasured` stream arrive.

So the question is: How to achieve such a lookup from one `WindowedStream` into another?

---

**Follow Up:**

After implementing in the way Fabian suggested, the job always fails with some sort of serialization issue:

```
[info] Loading project definition from /home/jgroeger/Code/MeasurementJob/project
[info] Set current project to MeasurementJob (in build file:/home/jgroeger/Code/MeasurementJob/)
[info] Compiling 8 Scala sources to /home/jgroeger/Code/MeasurementJob/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[info] Running de.company.project.Main dev MeasurementJob
[error] Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.api.common.InvalidProgramException: The implementation of the RichCoFlatMapFunction is not serializable. The object probably contains or references non serializable fields.
[error]     at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:100)
[error]     at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.clean(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1478)
[error]     at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream.clean(DataStream.java:161)
[error]     at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.ConnectedStreams.flatMap(ConnectedStreams.java:230)
[error]     at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.ConnectedStreams.flatMap(ConnectedStreams.scala:127)
[error]     at de.company.project.jobs.MeasurementJob.run(MeasurementJob.scala:139)
[error]     at de.company.project.Main$.main(Main.scala:55)
[error]     at de.company.project.Main.main(Main.scala)
[error] Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: de.company.project.jobs.MeasurementJob
[error]     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
[error]     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
[error]     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
[error]     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
[error]     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
[error]     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
[error]     at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.serializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:301)
[error]     at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:81)
[error]     ... 7 more
java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit code returned from runner: 1
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last MeasurementJob/compile:run for the full output.
[error] (MeasurementJob/compile:run) Nonzero exit code returned from runner: 1
[error] Total time: 9 s, completed Nov 15, 2016 2:28:46 PM

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The error message:

```
The implementation of the RichCoFlatMapFunction is not serializable. The object probably contains or references non serializable fields.
```

However, the only field my `JoiningCoFlatMap` has is the suggested `ValueState`.

The signature looks like this:

```
class JoiningCoFlatMap extends RichCoFlatMapFunction[Measurement, WhoMeasured, (Measurement, String)] {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want to do is a window operation followed by a join.

You can implement the a join of a high-volume stream and a low-value update-by-key stream using a stateful `CoFlatMapFunction` as in the example below:

```
val measures: DataStream[Measurement] = ???
val who: DataStream[WhoMeasured] = ???

val agg: DataStream[(Int, Long)] = measures
  .keyBy(_._2) // measured_by_id
  .timeWindow(Time.seconds(60), Time.seconds(5))
  .apply( (id: Int, w: TimeWindow, v: Iterable[(Int, Int, String)], out: Collector[(Int, Long)]) => {
    // do your aggregation
  })

val joined: DataStream[(Int, Long, String)] = agg
  .keyBy(_._1) // measured_by_id
  .connect(who.keyBy(_.who_measured_id))
  .flatMap(new JoiningCoFlatMap)

// CoFlatMapFunction
class JoiningCoFlatMap extends RichCoFlatMapFunction[(Int, Long), WhoMeasured, (Int, Long, String)] {

  var names: ValueState[String] = null

  override def open(conf: Configuration): Unit = {
    val stateDescrptr = new ValueStateDescriptor[String](
      "whoMeasuredName",
      classOf[String],
      ""                 // default value
    )
    names = getRuntimeContext.getState(stateDescrptr)
  }

  override def flatMap1(a: (Int, Long), out: Collector[(Int, Long, String)]): Unit = {
    // join with state
    out.collect( (a._1, a._2, names.value()) )
  }

  override def flatMap2(w: WhoMeasured, out: Collector[(Int, Long, String)]): Unit = {
    // update state
    names.update(w.name)
  }
}
```

A note on the implementation: A `CoFlatMapFunction` cannot decide which input to process, i.e., the `flatmap1` and `flatmap2` functions are called depending on what data arrives at the operator. It cannot be controlled by the function. This is a problem when initializing the state. In the beginning, the state might not have the correct name for an arriving `Measurement` object but return the default value. You can avoid that by buffering the measurements and joining them once, the first update for the key from the `who` stream arrives. You'll need another state for that.

Comment: The above code (with some minor changes to types) does not work for me. I added details of the error are in my initial post above.

Comment: It looks like you put the `RichCoFlatMapFunction` as in internal class into `MeasurementJob`. That's why Flink tries to serialize the whole `MeasurementJob` class. Can you move the `RichCoFlatMapFunction` to a separate file or out for the `MeasurementJob` class definition?